How to securely use JSON service account files for Firebase and Google Cloud APIs without exposing them on GitHub?
I am working on a project that generates short-form content for social media platforms. The back end uses Laravel, the front end uses React, and Firebase stores the video assets. Additionally, I use Google Cloud's Text-to-Speech API.
To integrate Firebase and Google Cloud APIs, I downloaded the JSON service account files from Google Console and placed them in my project’s root directory. However, when I push the project to my GitHub repository, these JSON files (containing sensitive credentials) get flagged by Google as exposed, and they are disabled for security reasons.
My question:
Is there a secure way to upload and manage these JSON files on my production server without pushing them to GitHub?
Thank you!

Did you consider sharing them with trusted collaborators outside of the (public) GitHub repo? E.g. on an intranet location, Google Drive, or even a private GitHub repo for such credentials.

I did the last thing that you mentioned. I made my repo private and then pushed my credentials there and immediately received an email from Google that my service account got disabled.

Oh wow, I didn't expect that alert to also apply to private repos.

I think I just found a way of solving this problem. Maybe I can save the credentials as github action secrets and try to push them to the server.

you have two way.

gcp secret manager
github secret

for gcp secret:
you can encode the json in base64 and add it in secret manager. after you get the secret in your function and decode from base64 in runtime.
(long opération for each runtime)
in github secret:
you can encode too but décode only in ci:cd or github secret provide you a file solution well you write directly the json without base64 step. ( work on gitlab not sûre for the file in github)
https://docs.github.com/fr/actions/security-for-github-actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#creating-secrets-for-an-environment
you can provide a service account for each environnement and stage local with your dev environnement in .gitignore

gitlab solution (best way)
On your local your path is get directly from the real json file : import credentials from "./your_path/credentials.json"
your credentials.json is in your .gitignore ok ?
after when you run your code in CiCd you can save secret (in base64) in cicd get the file from your secret on gitHub , decode and write in your path before build
this is my GitLab :
...
before_script:
    ...
    - echo "Deploying application..."
    //your secret var in base64
    - echo -n "$CREDENTIALS" | base64 -d > credentials.json

gcp secret
you can first JSON.stringify your credentials
after set in gcp secret
firebase functions:secret:set CREDENTIALS
// past strigified value in hidden field and enter


for access to your secret you can use :
const secretCredentials = defineSecret("CREDENTIALS")

const cred = JSON.parse(secretCredentials.value())


when you need to access on your local emulator you need to add

.secret.local

CREDENTIALS="{"youcredentials": "stringified"}"

for access secret outside of your firebase functions environement.

I did what you said. I actually put my secrets on google clouds using the secret manager.

when I tried to access the secrets locally. I got an error like this [2024-11-24 17:08:47] local.ERROR: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (Google\ApiCore\ValidationException(code: 0): Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials at  and this  Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc

Your code run in google cloud (cloud run, app engine , ... )   or in other env  ?
If you run outside of gcp github secret is best way for it
